# Tableau - How to calculate weekly and monthly averages based on daily data?

Tags: average, tableau-api

I have taken a COUNT DISTINCT to calculate all unique support tickets per day. Now I would like to find average number of tickets per week and per month. By average per week, I mean summing up the number of unique tickets of all days in a week and dividing by 7. The same for month. However, I cannot figure out how to do this in Tableau.

I have AGG(support_tickets). I cannot just take the Average(support_tickets) as you cannot average an aggregate. Also I have had no luck with window_AVG so far. I am not looking for the moving average. Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Tableau understands how dates work so, if you have a date field, you can automatically generate daily, weekly, monthly... aggregates of any measure that has an attached date. Does that not work?

Answer (score 0):

will the table calculation work for you? You can choose add a table calculation to your AGG(support_tickets) measures and then change to "Running Total" and choose "Avg" and then 7. Hope this help you.